# How can I concatenate multiple 1d list into one 2d list?

Tags: python, list

I have a dataset with 4 types in each data.
I'm trying to create a list of filenames, where each row consists of 4 types of data.

For example:

```
0 Input1_Original, Input1_2, Input1_4, Input1_8  
1 Input2_Original, Input2_2, Input2_4, Input2_8  
2 Input3_Original, Input3_2, Input3_4, Input3_8
```

Following is what I tried. 
Is there a better way?

```
self.raw_list = [None] * 4
self.raw_list[0] = sorted(glob.glob(args.raw_path + '/*_Original.raw'))
self.raw_list[1] = sorted(glob.glob(args.raw_path + '/*_2.raw'))
self.raw_list[2] = sorted(glob.glob(args.raw_path + '/*_4.raw'))
self.raw_list[3] = sorted(glob.glob(args.raw_path + '/*_8.raw'))

self.data_list = list()
for i in range(len(self.raw_list[0])):
    self.data_list.append([self.raw_list[x][i] for x in range(len(self.raw_list))])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop and string formatting to generate the `raw_list` of paths and then`zip(*...)` to 'rotate' the list of lists:

```
self.raw_list = []
for file_type in "Original", 2, 4, 8:
    group = sorted(glob.glob("{}/*_{}.raw".format(args.raw_path, file_type)))
    self.raw_list.append(group) 
self.data_list = list(zip(*self.raw_list))
```

If you intend to manipulate this information as a table then it may be worth using a `pandas DataFrame` instead:

```
import pandas as pd
...
self.data = pd.DataFrame(self.raw_list).T    # T to transpose the table
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.chain`:

```
from glob import glob
from itertools import chain

filenames = '/*_Original.raw', '/*_2.raw', '/*_4.raw', '/*_8.raw'
path = args.raw_path

self.raw_list = [glob(path + name) for name in filenames]
self.data_list = list(chain(*raw_list))
```